# autosum from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I currently have a workbook with multiple worksheets, including a master worksheet. My current VBA provides a sum total for specified columns in the master worksheet and this works perfectly well.

However, I would like to edit the VBA so I can have sum values for columns on different worksheets too. I have attached the code for reference below, if anyone can suggest how I might edit it in order to include more than one worksheet would be greatly appreciated.

```
`Sub AutoSum()
Sheets("MASTER ACCOUNT REVENUE").Select
Range("D4").Select
Range("F4").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
Dim cel1 As String, cel2 As String
cel1 = ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).End(xlUp).Address
cel2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Address
ActiveCell.Value = "=sum(" & (cel1) & ":" & (cel2) & ")"
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three worksheets with a value in "A1." This subroutine shows the sum of all of those values in the cell "A2" on the worksheet in which the code resides:

```
Sub sum()

Range("a2") = Worksheets(2).Range("a1") + Worksheets(3).Range("a1") + Range("a1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! However is there a way to autosum for a predefined column? My VBA sums for a column downwards and stops when there is no more data in the column to sum.

Comment: `lrow = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  
Worksheets(1).Range("A" & lrow + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("A1:A" & lrow))`   will sum up the values in column A and display the sum after the last row.

Comment: Thank you @oxwilder, this has worked! I had one other question. As I will be adding worksheets to this workbook everyday, is there a way to have the vba set so that it sums the same columns for each new worksheet which I add? This will save me having to go into the vba and adding the worksheet and cell range every time which will become tedious. Thank you!

Comment: When you're applying an action to the same range of cells through different worksheets, you can use a `for each` loop. See some of the vba tutorials for more information on that since I wouldn't be able to go into sufficient detail here, but basically you'll say "for every worksheet in (the collection of) worksheets..." apply some action. Best of luck.